# Problem with selecting jQuery id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I apply `onclick`

I gave the node #ac id #Goster ID to content

ac id si shows the contents when I click the button in the 1st field, but in the loop where the 2nd field is not opened

This is my code block.

```
$("Body").One("click", "# add comment", function () {
    $("# List").Fadetogglto();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a PHP question???

Comment: Forgive me if this is the first time I use this site Do you have any idea about the question?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't really match the IDs and named you've mentioned in the description. Also your description mentions a loop, which the code doesn't have. It's unclear how the code and the description are related. And the code itself has some strange spaces in the ID selectors, which are not allowed in HTML. Lastly, as well as clarifying the question, can you show the related HTML as well please? It's very hard to understand what is happening or what you are describing.

Comment: JQuery $(function(){



 $("body").on("click",".yorum-ekle",function(){


    var post_id=$(this).attr("id");
    $("#listele").fadeToggle();
              



      

});